# Não está trazendo os dados com múltiplos filtros em uma Table mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, table

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT * from SALDO_GERAL";
$i = 0;
$selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['LOCAL']);
$selectedOptionCount2 = count($_POST['net']);
$selectedOption = "";
$selectedOption2 = "";
while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
$selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['LOCAL'][$i] . "'"; 
$selectedOption2 = $selectedOption2 . "'" . $_POST['net'][$i] . "'";
if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
$selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
}
$i ++;
    }
$query = $query . " WHERE LOCAL = (" . $selectedOption . "  AND net = " . $selectedOption2 . ")";
$result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
}
if (! empty($result)) {
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
?>
```

Comment: cara, pra começar, por que você está definindo a query no início do código pra só depois concatenar às clausulas WHERE? e você pricisa passar mais informações sobre seu código e sobre o erro apresentado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está na linha:

```
$query . " WHERE **LOCAL = (" . $selectedOption . "  AND net = " . $selectedOption2 . ")**";
```

deve retirar os parênteses na chamada, coloca assim:

```
$query . " WHERE **LOCAL IN (" . $selectedOption . ")  AND net = '" . $selectedOption2 . "'**";
```

MYSQL: WHERE column_name IN (SELECT STATEMENT);

Simplifica esse código:

```
$query = "SELECT * from SALDO_GERAL";
$i = 0;
$selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['LOCAL']);
$selectedOptionCount2 = count($_POST['net']);
$selectedOption = "";
$selectedOption2 = "";
while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
$selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['LOCAL'][$i] . "'"; 
$selectedOption2 = $selectedOption2 . "'" . $_POST['net'][$i] . "'";
if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
$selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
}
$i ++;
    }
```

Dica:
Concatenar usando ' .= ' ao invés de repetir a variavel:

```
$query = "SELECT * from SALDO_GERAL";
$i = 0;

$selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['LOCAL']);
$selectedOptionCount2 = count($_POST['net']);
$selectedOption = "";
$selectedOption2 = "";

while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
    $selectedOption .= "'" . $_POST['LOCAL'][$i] . "'"; 
    $selectedOption2 .= "'" . $_POST['net'][$i] . "'";
    if ($i < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
        $selectedOption .= ", ";
    }
    $i ++;
}
```

ou usa função nativa do php -> implode():

```
$query = "SELECT * from SALDO_GERAL";

if ( is_array( $_POST['LOCAL'] ) ){
    $selectedOption = "'" . implode("', '", $_POST['LOCAL']) . "'";
}
if ( is_array( $_POST['net'] ) ){
    $selectedOption2 = "'" . implode("', '", $_POST['net']) . "'";
}
```